# widlfly Apache Camel Installation and run

Tags: java, apache-camel, wildfly, apache-camel-cdi

Does not understand how to run wildfly 10 Apache Camel/CDI project and how to install widlfly camel pack.
getting started guide does not show where to unpack downloaded subsystem .
https://wildflyext.gitbooks.io/wildfly-camel/content/start/
What does it mean "Simply unpack the provided patch into the a supported WildFly installation." ?

```
my wildfly in C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final, I extracted
C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\wildfly-camel-patch-4.0.0 .
Camel config file in C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\wildfly-camel-patch-4.0.0\standalone\configuration\standalone-full-camel.xml
```

in https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel/tree/master/examples/camel-cdi example i should start the server like

```
C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.bat -c  standalone-full-camel.xml
```

but i have exception

```
22:24:53,580 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0214: Could not get main file: standalone-full-camel.xml. Specified files must be relative to the configuration dir: C:\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.determineMainFile(ConfigurationFile.java:311)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFile.<init>(ConfigurationFile.java:172)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:456)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:297)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:94)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:329)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:507)
```

So how can i fix it? What is the best way configuring Apache Camel with wildfly? No one example are work.

I am using ApacheCamel with Spring under tomcat 8, all fine, but with wildfly I cant run simple camel CDI example.